# Jquery buttonset sizing issue with image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, imagebutton

I have a buttonset that is mostly comprised of single characters for each button. In one of the buttons there is an image. Unfortunately the button containing the image doesn't align itself correctly with the rest of the images in it's buttonset, and it isn't the correct height either. If a screenshot is needed, this can be provided.

---

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLwmC/) that accurately represents the issue that I'm having. Preferably I would like a solution that works on any size image though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring it out. The `vertical-align` property was being set to baseline, so I changed that to `top`. Also, I changed any image inside of a button to be the size of the rest of the buttons using this css snippet.

```
span.ui-button-text > img{
  height: 1.1em; // This is jQuery UI default font-size for buttons.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can picture what your issue is. I'd recommend using [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)
 and place your code in it so we can get a look at what might be the issue, or as you said, a screenshot. If it's CSS related, i'd take my chances on the vertical-align property for that specific case? I may be way off, though.